# Text swatch value for multi store view showing wrong on frontend [ Magento 2.3.3 Enterprise Edition]

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, swatches, color-swatches

Have a look at below. Did anyone get the solution for this?

Why product text swatch display admin swatch value instead of specific store value?

Magento EE [2.3.3]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create 2 websites with 1 store view each or just 2 store views
2. Create configurable select attribute (eg size) with different store
   view value and label.
3. Now go to frontend, default store (GB) and load any category page with
   configurable products with size as one of the attributes.

Now switch to a different website/ store view (US)

**Expected result:**

Once we switch to the website/store view(US), we should see the size's value to show according to the value set for that specific store view in the attribute edit section.

**Actual result:**

When we switch from the default website/store view(GB) to the US store view, it still shows the GB store view attribute option values instead of the US store values.

Answer (score 0):

Text swatch value for multi-store view wrong on frontend [ Magento 2.3.3 Enterprise Edition]

Please refer below URL:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27635